# Database manipulation through python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have made a database using python. I have made a class to manipulate the database to insert a record 'Charlie' into the database however an error occurs. The error seems a bit vague and I can't figure out what is causing it.

```
import sqlite3


class create_db:  # class to create database
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("EXAMPLE.db")  # connects to database
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_tables(self, Tables):  # for each table in Tables, create table with field and table names 
        for table_name, field in Tables.items():
            self.c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table_name + '(' + field + ')')  # creates table
            self.conn.commit()


class customer_table(create_db):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def data_entry(self, Customer_Name):  # adds a record to database
        self.data_tuple = (Customer_Name,)
        self.sql = 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(CustomerID, Customer_Name), values(?,?)'  # sql to inset into customers
        self.c.execute(self.sql, self.data_tuple)
        self.conn.commit()


def main():
    db = create_db()
    tables = {"CUSTOMERS": '''CustomerID integer,
    Customer_Name text,
    primary key (CustomerID)'''}  # Dictionary of tables and fields

    db.create_tables(tables)
    customer = customer_table()
    customer.data_entry("Charlie")


main()
```

Error:     `self.c.execute(self.sql, self.data_tuple) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Comment: You need to figure out a way to see the SQL statement that is causing the error.  If you put a try/except block around your SQL executions, then when you catch an error you could print the SQL that generated the error.  Is that the whole error message that you show?  Make sure you are putting the entire error message into your question, including any stack trace that you are getting with th error.

Answer (score 1):

Your sqlite insert isnt valid. An insert shouldnt have a comma before the values. you also need to pass 2 items in your data tuple as you have 2 bindings

```py
class customer_table(create_db):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def data_entry(self, Customer_Name):  # adds a record to database
        self.data_tuple = (123, Customer_Name)
        self.sql = 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(CustomerID, Customer_Name) values(?,?)'  # sql to inset into customers
        self.c.execute(self.sql, self.data_tuple)
        self.conn.commit()
```